# Add Cache-control: no-cache,no-store metadata to object uploaded via S3 Publisher plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-s3

So i have a jenkins job that builds a project and then uploads specific files to an S3 bucket.

I've set up the S3 Publisher plugin shown in the attached image, but the metadata is still not being added to objects.

[image: Job Configuration Page: S3 Publisher Entry for object with Metadata information]

Is it because the plugin prefixes Metadata keys with "x-amz-meta-"?